# How to Manipulate data to display appropriate html layout asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I come from a procedural PHP background. I am trying to learn how to do the same stuff I used to do in php and do it in asp.net. I need to sort my orders under their perspective Customer name.
Right now my layout is:

- **Sams Club**
- Order 1
- **Sams Club**
- Order 2
- **Walmart**
- Order 1
- **Walmart**
- Order 2
- **Walmart**
- Order 3

I need my layout more like:

- **Sams Club**
- Order 1
- Order 2
- **Walmart**
- Order 1
- Order 2
- Order 3

I can easily do this with PHP but am struggling to figure out how to do this in an MVC type of application.
This is how my cshtml page looks.

```
     <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="CheckOrders" />Select All </th>
                <th>Bill to Name</th>
                <th>Qty Ordered</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {    
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.customer_number)" class="accordion-toggle">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkAllCus" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.customer_number)"/></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Bill_to_Name)
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Quantity_Ordered)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.customer_number)">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                       <th></th>
                                       <th>Order Number</th>
                                       <th>Bill to Name</th>
                                       <th>Qty Ordered</th>
                                       <th>Ship Date</th>
                                       <th>Item #</th>
                                       <th>Description</th>
                                       <th>State</th>
                                       <th>Carrier</th>
                                       <th>Details</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="orders[]" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.order_no)" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.order_no)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Bill_to_Name)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Quantity_Ordered)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Ship_Date)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.item_no)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.descr1)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.shipstate)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.shipper)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                                        </td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is my Model

```
namespace OpenCustomerOrder3.Models
{
    using System;

    public partial class spOrderDetails_Result
    {
        public string cusNo;
        public string customer_number { get; set; }
        public string shipper { get; set; }
        public string user_def_fld_5 { get; set; }
        public string item_no { get; set; }
        public string descr1 { get; set; }
        public string location1 { get; set; }
        public string Bill_to_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Quantity_Ordered { get; set; }
        public string Requested_Date { get; set; }
        public string Ship_Date { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string order_no { get; set; }
        public string shipstate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating this list? I would change it to Name + List of Orders, instead of Name + Order

Comment: I'm not sure how your Model is currently set up, but the simplest way to handle this, I think, would be to have a Model that is an IEnumerable<Customer>, assuming your Customer model has the collection of Orders inside of it.  Then your view basically becomes two foreach loops - loop through each Customer in the Model to create the Row, then loop through each Order in the Customer to create the Cells.  If you can post your Model, and what this page is actually supposed to do, I can give a better answer.

Comment: Ive got @model IEnumerable<OpenCustomerOrder3.Models.spOrderDetails_Result>
at the top of my view. Each row of order data has a customer number attached to it.

Comment: Ok I have posted my model...

Comment: @Ryan so you want to order the list by `Bill_to_Name`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yes, either that or customer number those are the same thing

Comment: @Ryan ahh I am sorry, I misread your question.. working on a solution!

Comment: Nikkster is leading you down the right path.  I would suggest creating a ViewModel for what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to what your domain model looks like.

It looks like the model type being passed to the view at the moment is simply an `IEnumerable<Order>` or similar. If you really have to do this way, one way to achieve what you want is by grouping your orders by `CustomerName` using the `GroupBy` method in `System.Linq`.

However, a better model would be to let a Customer model have many orders, i.e. between Customer and Order there is a 1..* relationship. For example,

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then what you want is to pass an `IEnumerable<Customer>` instead to your view.